# Copying content of a file without any dynamic memory allocation functions

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I'm doing some programming for an old system which has unreliable dynamic memory allocation functions (malloc, calloc, realloc, etc...).

I started toying with the idea of loading a file without using any of those functions. Designate a pointer with a memory address on which I would get the file content loaded, this pointer would increase as I iterate through the file copying the content I need to my struct variables or assigning the pointers of my internal structs to this new address. Any new file would be loaded at the end address of the previous one.

for a simple structs likes this:

```
typedef struct A
{
  int a;
  int b;
  int c;
}A;

A a;
```

I copy the content with a simple memcpy and then increase the pointer

```
memcpy(&a, pointer_to_the_file, sizeof(A));
pointer_to_the_file += sizeof(A)
```

This worked fine. For structs on which before I would use some dynamic allocations like:

```
typedef struct B
{
  A* p_a;
  A* p_b;
}B;

B b;
```

I assign the pointers directly:

```
b->p_a = (B *)pointer_to_the_file; 

//then increase the pointer
pointer_to_the_file += sizeof(B) * num_of_p_a_elements;
```

This also seemed to work OK.
But it was when I move to more complex structures that I started having some problems:

```
typedef struct C
{
  A   p_a_1;
  A*  p_a_2;
  B** p_b;
}C;

C *p_c;
```

Here I don't know how to approach it correctly. I did:

```
p_c = (C *)pointer_to_the_file;
```

But I did not get the expected results for **p_a_1**, although the address of **p_c** was pointing at the right location where the correct values for **p_a_1** were located. I tried using **C p_c[0];** and then the values of  **p_a_1** were correct, but I don't know why that is working so I don't want to build it upon this and then find out later on it causes issues.
Also, I cannot wrap my head about how could I assign **p_c->p_b** (a non square 2d matrix) using the [0] trick.

Is this at all possible (reading structs like this from a file without using dnyamic memory alloc functions)? If so, what would be the best approach to do it?

Comment: Well... how does it make sense to store pointers in a file?

Comment: how is `C->p_c` correct? You structure `C` does not declare a member names `p_c`

Comment: @Ackdari I made a typo in the text (it was meant to be p_c only)

Comment: If understand you correct you want to load a file and then parse it's content to your structure `C` without using dynamic memory, is that correct?

Comment: yes, if that's possible

Comment: Also do you know why the dynamic memory allocationas are unreliable and can you detecte if they are?

Comment: This is from the first Playstation, appartently the dynamic mem alloc they implemented in the bios (which is the ones I can use) end up corrupting the memory, but I don't know the specifics

Comment: Structs may contain paddings. Is your ` += sizeof(B)`  correct?

Comment: The structs I put here are just examples, but yeah I made sure all structs were 32 bits aligned (adding paddings if necessary). I also run a function right before the pointer assignments to check if the address at that point is still 32 bit aligned and they are

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two routes for this:

Either you use some global variables and implement you own memory allocation (and maybe even replace the one for `malloc` and co. by linking two your implementation).

Or you a globale buffer to read chunks of the files into memory, like:

```c
uint8_t buffer[1024];

int read_chunk(int fd) {
    int bytes_read = 0;

    while (bytes_read < 1024) {
        ssize_t res = read(fd, &buffer + bytes_read, 1024 - bytes_read);

        if (res < 0) return -1;
        else if (res == 0) break;
        else {
            bytes_read += res;      
        }
    }

    return bytes_read;
}
```

and then with a function with the signature

```c
void parse(uint8_t* data, C* p_c);
```

you can parse you file in stack allocated mempory like.

```c
C p_cs[2];
read_chunk(fd);
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    parse(&buffer + (sizeof(C)*i), &p_cs[i]);
}
```

But imho you should go with the first suggestion if possible.

Comment: I was on the fence about writing a simple memory allocation function but I guess you are right and that's the way to go. Thanks so much for taking the time to write the answer!